# Insert values from max table value using MYSql

Tags: mysql, database

I have table called `CusPayment`

```
PID     Date        No      TotalPaid
8523    05-Oct-14   GB0213  $300.00
8523    08-Nov-14   GB0213  $500.00
12659   28-Nov-14   N02007  $100.00
12659   07-Dec-14   N02007  $200.00
8523    07-Dec-14   GB0213  $700.00
12659   04-Jan-15   N02007  $300.00
8523    04-Jan-15   GB0213  $900.00
```

and I would like insert the `max TotalPaid` based on `CardNo`, the result is

```
PID       Date      CardNo  TotalPaid
8523    07-Dec-14   GB0213  $700.00
12659   04-Jan-15   N02007  $300.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `insert into select` clause

If there are two maximum values for the same card on different dates you will be picking both

```
insert into Table1 
select c.pid, c.date, c.cardno, c.TotalPaid 
from cusPayment c 
join ( select cardno, max(TotalPaid) as maxPaid 
       from CusPayment group by cardno ) t 
on c.cardno = t.cardno and c.TotalPaid = t.maxPaid
```